# Jupyter Creating Notebook failed: FORBIDDEN

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have just upgraded Jupyter to the version 4.3.1
While I can open previously created ipynb files, I cannot create new ones.

When I try to create a new notebook file, I get a pop up windows saying:
Creating Notebook Failed
An error occurred while creating a new notebook
Forbidden

In the terminal I notice this output:

```
[W 12:53:23.375 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (::1): '_xsrf' argument missing from POST
[W 12:53:23.383 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (::1) 8.92ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree?token=e7fbbb58516dc1359fcc26a1079093166a1f713ee5b94ccd
```

I use Jupyter with Python 3.5.2 and IPython 5.1.0

Comment: Possibly caused by the new mandatory token authentication that was added to jupyter. http://blog.jupyter.org/2016/12/21/jupyter-notebook-4-3-1/

Comment: This might be a bug. At least the error message should have been more informative. Maybe you should submit a bug report at the github issue tracker for jupyter-notebook?
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook

Comment: This happened to me when I cleaned my browser cookies while my jupyter notebook was opened in my browser.

Answer (score 21):

Another alternative to confirm the issue is to open your Jupyter Session in another browser and you might be redirected to a screen like the following:

[image]

If you open a new console and type

```
jupyter notebook list
```

You'll see your current notebook and the URL will contain a token. Open that in a new tab and problem solved.

Output command should look like this:

```
Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8888/?token=cbad1a6ce77ae284725a5e43a7db48f2e9bf3b6458e577bb :: <path to notebook>
```

Comment: This applies if you've got a book open that suddenly stops allowing checkpoints to be saved.  Apparently the password times out?  Opening a new window and entering the password in the new window will re-enable the save function on the open tab.

Comment: i simply pasted the token in the browser, and now it worked

Answer (score 8):

I had to enable cookies in the browser (which I had intentionally disabled). Then the "Forbidden" error disappeared, everything is OK now.

> The generally accepted solution to prevent XSRF is to cookie every user with an unpredictable value and include that value as an additional argument with every form submission on your site.

From: http://tornado.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-protection

Answer (score 5):

Jupyter blocks non-local requests. To access Jupyter from an external address we can execute it with the following parameters:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin=* --NotebookApp.allow_remote_access=1
```

Comment: Now according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/74716990/13040423, change `NotebookApp` to `ServerApp`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem just now, but I noticed that it worked in Edge. Deleting all browser cache including cookies in Chrome solved this in my case.