# configuration error when initializing jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Following is the information of error when initializing `Jupyter lab`. The error seems not serious, but I cannot open the webpage. How do I fix it? To my surprise, `Jupyter notebook` works well.

> [~] jupyter lab
>
> [I ... ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was
> successfully linked. [W 2021-08-28 11:32:26.627 NotebookApp] 'browser'
> has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to
> ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.

> [W ... NotebookApp] 'notebook_dir' has moved from
> NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be
> sure to update your config before our next release.

> [C ... NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during
> initialization: Trait, server_extensions, not found.

Thanks for the helps. All errors are vanished, except the last info: Bad config encountered during initialization: Trait, server_extensions, not found.

There is a json file in configuration dir, it writes

```
{
  "NotebookApp": {
    "server_extensions": [
      "jupyter_nbextensions_configurator"
    ],
    "nbserver_extensions": {
      "jupyterlab": true
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, I reinstall `jupyterlab` after delete the config dir. It just works now. I should end the topic.

Comment: Please refer to this link, this works for JupyterLab:

Answer (score 3):

If your Jupyter log shows `"has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp"` warnings you should migrate from `notebook` server to `jupyter` server, thus:

- rename (with backup) Jupyter config from `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` to `jupyter_server_config.py`, and
- in the new config file rename all non-default (i.e. uncommented) `c.NotebookApp.*` entires to `c.ServerApp.*` (the entries to rename are shown in the log warnings as "moved" ones)