# How to change the root directory for the Jupyter notebook in Windows?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I can't «persuade» Jupyter to use another directory then the default one for storing its projects.

I edited the following parameter of the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file (I tried all three variants one-by-one, none worked):

```
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'D:\\_Travail\\Python\\Jupyter_projects'
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = r'D:\_Travail\Python\Jupyter_projects'
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'D:/_Travail/Python/Jupyter_projects'
```

Besides, I tried to rename the config-file (and names of parameters therein) exactly as described in the only answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961192/configuration-error-when-initializing-jupyter-lab) (I also have this message `'notebook_dir' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.` in console).

I wonder if it is important but the disk D: where I want files stored is a network drive connected to another machine on LAN.

Comment: i run a Jupyter notebook in `vscode` from anywhere i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch the Jupyter in the directory you want.
Open Anaconda Prompt and enter the following statement:

`jupyter notebook --notebook-dir "your-directory"`

Comment: You are right, that works. Thank you! It seems the most obvious option just did not occur to me.

Comment: It also works with WinPython using the WinPython Command Prompt. I type:
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir "C:\XXX\YYY (for the old style Jupyter notebooks) or jupyter lab --notebook-dir "C:\XXX\YYY"  (for Jupyter Lab)