# WinPython Path for Jupyter notebooks does not seems to respond to os.chdir()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using a portable Python distribution (WinPythyon 2023-04), and downloaded a set of notebooks from a public GitHub repository (https://github.com/kenperry-public/ML_Spring_2024) using GitHub Desktop on Windows 11 to C:\Users....\Github\ML_Spring_2024.

I started Jupyter Lab from the WinPython directory, opened a .ipynb notebook located in C:\Users....\Github\ML_Spring_2024 and started work by inserting and executing a new cell right at the top:

import os
os.chdir("C:\Users....\Github\ML_Spring_2024")

Unfortunately, the links in the notebook (which are relative links) did not work. I then noticed that WinPython had created a copy of the .ipynb file that I opened in C:\WPy64-31160\notebooks. If I copy all the files and subdirectories in C:\Users....\Github\ML_Spring_2024 to C:\WPy64-31160\notebooks, all the links in my open Jupyter notebook work. It seems as if my working directory has not changed on account of my os.chdir() coommand. This is very inconvenient.

How do I get WinPython to change its working directory for Jupyter notebooks to the location to which I point it with os.chdir()?

Sincerely and with many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: Are you using `%cd` in the running `.ipynb` file to change the directory? The `os` part of your current route is referring to your operating system. Jupyter runs in its own location that may be separate from your system settings. See `about the magic change directory command `%cd` [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd). After you use it, you can use `pwd` in your running `.ipynb` file to check it worked. Also then use `ls` to check the relative paths you are using.

Comment: And you can change the root directory at the start up of Jupyter using that approach similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77954240/8508004). You may need to change the start of the command if you are using JupyterLab and not the document-centric Jupyter UI.

Comment: Thank you Wayne - the %cd didn't work, but your pointer to changing the root directory at startup did. I opened a WinPython command prompt and typed 
`jupyter notebook --notebook-dir "C:\DIRNAME"`
(for a old-style Jupyter notebook)
And
`jupyter lab --notebook-dir "C:\DIRNAME"` for a Jupyter Lab instance. Both work beautifully.

Comment: That's great. I am still surprised a bit about `%cd` not working in the notebook, but I don't work on Windows and so maybe I'm forgetting a nuance needed there.