# Jupyter Notebook 302, 403, 401 forbidden error and connection refused error when trying to stop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

My terminal logs are filled with 401 and 403 errors when I open jupyter notebook within a conda environment on a remote machine in Ubuntu. Just like this issue here: [Jupyter Creating Notebook failed: FORBIDDEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532441/jupyter-creating-notebook-failed-forbidden)

Then I tried what one of the answers to check:

```
~$jupyter notebook list

Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8888/?token=0f2ad000db9......
http://0.0.0.0:8899/?token=7aa2a13503d.....
```

It's easy to shutdown the second one, as I just ssh into port 8899 and open the browser with the link to shutdown. But I can't shut down the first one, when I ssh into port 8888, the link won't work in browser. And when I do

```
~$ jupyter notebook stop
Shutting down server on 8888...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sivan/.conda/envs/speech/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/sivan/.conda/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 269, in launch_instance
    return super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sivan/.conda/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 976, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/sivan/.conda/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2307, in start
    super().start()
  File "/home/sivan/.conda/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 258, in start
    self.subapp.start()
  File "/home/sivan/.conda/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 559, in start
    self._shutdown_or_exit(port, server)
  File "/home/sivan/.conda/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 525, in _shutdown_or_exit
    server_stopped = self.shutdown_server(server)
  File "/home/sivan/.conda/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 521, in shutdown_server
    return shutdown_server(server, log=self.log)
  File "/home/sivan/.conda/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 474, in shutdown_server
    HTTPClient(AsyncHTTPClient).fetch(req)
  File "/home/sivan/.conda/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/httpclient.py", line 134, in fetch
    response = self._io_loop.run_sync(
  File "/home/sivan/.conda/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 529, in run_sync
    return future_cell[0].result()
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I then referred to this https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-keeps-starting-up-automatically-and-impossible-to-kill/13723

```
~$ ps -ef|grep jupyter
sivan     5865  5529  0 15:48 pts/5    00:00:00 grep --color=auto jupyter
```

Why this happens and what should I do now? I can still open and use jupyter but it's really unstable and usually breakdown. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the "no server running but something in jupyter list" thing by following this post.....
https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-does-jupyter-notebook-list-show-running-instances-when-no-jupyter-server-running/12785

So simply remove the orphaned json file in the jupyter runtime folder.

```
jupyter --paths

cd <runtime folder>
ls

rm nbserver-<pid>.json
```

However, I still got these errors messing up my workflow..