# Constant HTTP 403: Forbidden Errors on External Jupyter Server Despite Successful Kernel Access

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-venv

I'm experiencing a recurring issue with my Jupyter server setup on an external Debian server (version 6.1.76-1, 2024-02-01, x86_64). Despite being able to open and use the Jupyter kernel without any apparent issues, I am constantly getting `HTTP 403: Forbidden` errors logged to the command line.

**Environment:**

- Running in a virtual environment (python-venv)
- Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64

**Error Log:**

```
[W 2024-02-23 16:34:06.445 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mlappert/batterypipeline/venv_batterypipeline/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/home/mlappert/batterypipeline/venv_batterypipeline/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3289, in wrapper
    url = self.get_login_url()
  File "/home/mlappert/batterypipeline/venv_batterypipeline/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 763, in get_login_url
    raise web.HTTPError(403)
tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-02-23 16:34:06.445 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1708702446295 (@127.0.0.1) 1.39ms referer=None
```

**Package Versions:**

- Python 3.11.2
- IPython: 8.22.1
- ipykernel: 6.29.2
- ipywidgets: 8.1.2
- jupyter_client: 8.6.0
- jupyter_core: 5.7.1
- jupyter_server: 2.12.5 (Note: I attempted downgrading Jupyter server < 2.0.0 as a troubleshooting step)
- jupyterlab: 4.1.2
- nbclient: 0.9.0
- nbconvert: 7.16.1
- nbformat: 5.9.2
- notebook: 7.1.0
- qtconsole: 5.5.1
- traitlets: 5.14.1

**Steps I've Taken:**

- I've explored solutions from similar Stack Overflow threads ([Jupyter Notebook `403 Forbidden` errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74062033/jupyter-notebook-302-403-401-forbidden-error-and-connection-refused-error-when) and [creating notebooks forbidden issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532441/jupyter-creating-notebook-failed-forbidden)) without any resolution.
- Downgraded the jupyter_server package to a version below 2.0.0 based on some suggestions, but reverted to 2.12.5 after seeing no change.
- Despite these error messages, I can access and interact with the Jupyter kernel as expected. The issue is with the continuous logging of `403 Forbidden` errors.
- Uninstall and reinstall the jupyter package

**Questions:**

- What could be the root cause of these `403 Forbidden` errors being logged, despite the Jupyter server's functionalities seemingly operating normally?
- Have I missed any Debian-specific or Jupyter server configurations that might resolve this error logging?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions to eliminate these `403 Forbidden` error logs. It's really strange that the server operates normally for user interactions yet continuously logs these errors.